# Vue multiple questions, with each question having multiple options

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-for

I have a list of properties in my database. I want the user to select the type of houses in the property.

| Property | Selected property types |
| --- | --- |
| Property 1 | ['studio_apartment', 'one_bedroom', 'two_bedroom'] |
| Property 2 | ['studio_apartment', 'one_bedroom'] |

To achieve this I am using the Vue v-for loop as follows:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(name, index) in propertyNames" :key="index">
    NAME: {{ name }}<br />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      value="studio_apartment"
      v-model="form.property_type"
    />Studio apartment<br />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      value="one_bedroom"
      v-model="form.property_type"
    />One bedroom<br />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      value="two_bedroom"
      v-model="form.property_type"
    />Two bedroom<br />

    SELECTED: {{}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        property_type: [],
      },
    };
  },

</script>
```

The problem is when I select for example `studio_apartment` in property 1, then all the properties `studio_apartment` is checked. How do I only get the selected checkboxes for each property individually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because there's only one `form` instance being shared in each loop iteration.

You could change `form` into an object array based on `propertyNames`, so that they have the same array length; then index into `form` with the iteration `index` of `v-for`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(name, index) in propertyNames" :key="index">
      NAME: {{ name }}<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="studio_apartment" v-model="form[index].property_type">Studio apartment<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="one_bedroom" v-model="form[index].property_type">One bedroom<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="two_bedroom" v-model="form[index].property_type">Two bedroom<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    const propertyNames = ['Property 1', 'Property 2']
    return {
      propertyNames,
      form: propertyNames.map(name => ({ property_type: [] }))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/poNdPbx)

Comment: Is there a way to replace const propertyNames = ['Property 1', 'Property 2'] with a computed property? I have the following computed property:  computed: {
     propertyNames() {
            const properties = this.property_form.property_name;
            const filtered = properties.filter(p => p != null)

            return filtered;
        }
}, and I want it to be: const propertyNames = this.propertyNames

Comment: If `propertyNames` is a computed prop, you'd have to use a watcher on it that updates `form` based on the new value.