# Vue use computed property in data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following `const properties` in my Vue data.

```
 <script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
data() {
    const properties = ['Property 1', 'Property 2']
    return {
        properties,
        form: propertyNames.map(name => ({ property_type: [] })),
    }

  },
```

I however am computing the properties in a computed property as follows

```
computed: {
 
     properties() {
            const properties = this.property_form.property_name;
            const filtered = properties.filter(p => p != null)

            return filtered;
        }
},
```

so I want to use the computed property in the data as follows:

```
 <script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
data() {
    const properties = this.properties
    return {
        properties,
        form: propertyNames.map(name => ({ property_type: [] })),
    }

  },
```

but when I do this, I get the error `Property or method "properties" is not defined on the instance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data()` is invoked before computed props are resolved, so you can't reference computed props from there.

I assume this question is related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66334379/vue-multiple-questions-with-each-question-having-multiple-options), where `form` needs to be used in `v-model`. Since `form` depends on the computed prop, you should use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the computed prop that updates `form` accordingly:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    properties() {/*...*/},
  },
  watch: {
    properties(properties) {
      this.form = properties.map(_ => ({ property_type: [] }))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `const properties = ['Property 1', 'Property 2']` ?

Pretty sure you cannot have it nested inside of `data`. Move it to the upper scope maybe or define it directly like

```js
data() {
  return {
    properties: ['Property 1', 'Property 2']
  }
}
```

Also, it's not very clear as of what you're trying to achieve here. A lot of things are mixed together. You're not really supposed to make a map in `data` since it's here for raw data (as it's called).

Here is the official documentation on [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), maybe give it a second read or update your question by explaining a bit better what is happening here.